# Is there a way to run chrome devtools in a different thread (or otherwise debug CPU 100% cases)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

Title pretty much says it all. When developing web apps, the nastiest stuff to debug are the cases where the app gets stuck somehow, as there is absolutely zero help from the debugger.

Comment: I agree, it would be useful if that was possible. Don't know if it is. At least in Chrome, you get one tab being unresponsive - in Firefox, the entire browser freezes which is...less than ideal if you want to switch to a different tab and do something else.

Comment: /*tried doing this but wont work...*/ function detectFreeze(){
    var n = $.now()
    if(n-2000>this.time && this.time){
     debugger;
    }
    this.time=n;
    setTimeout(detectFreeze,1000);
   }
   if(window.debug)
    detectFreeze();

Comment: I think your detectFreeze won't work because javascript uses an event loop on the main thread, if your code is running an infinite loop, then no events will then fire while in the loop.  I've not tested but maybe using a webWorker might work though..  eg. in the main thread you could maybe use a setInterval, that postMessage's to the webWorker, if the webWorker doesn't get a message after x amount of time, call debugger.

Comment: Yeah, but in this case I think the loop was a series of setTimeouts (not sure as it's black magic internals of react). Will give the webworker a try now.

Comment: @Keith altho arent the webworkers at a different context and hence unable to launch debugger?